# Which winForm control is using for that?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to create a winform in c# like this :

[image: Here is the winform]

I woule like to reproduce the zone in blue.
Which contrôle i need to use please ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Answer (score 5):

There is an API called [`DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can use it directly with p/invoke ([example on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15394/Drawing-smooth-text-and-pictures-on-the-extended-g)).

However there seems to be lots of wrappers for c#, like [Windows Forms Aero](http://windowsformsaero.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Like you can see, it's a standard form in Windows 7 / 8.

Comment: Yes, should be the same API, it is just less glassy on Windows 7/8.

Comment: You should not Extend the frame to the whole form as in the Code Project article, but only the top a bit and maybe the sides a tiny bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! In addition, there is a nugget package in C# works which very well : http://nuget.org/packages/AeroWizard

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you can reproduce it using a standard form, with a `BackColor` set to blue (instead of the default color), and a panel in it which has `BackColor` set to white (instead of the default transparent).  To get the X as the only thing on top, you need to toggle the `MinimizeBox` and `MaximizeBox` properties to false (see [here](http://dotnetdud.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-disable-minimize-button-on.html) for a short example).

Does that help?

Comment: Your application will look very broken on Windows Vista and Windows 7 if you paint it blue. And probably in Windows 9 too.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo - If you want a blue form, you make it blue.  If you want it system-default, you leave it system-default.  The requirements may be for an application which looks "broken".  Your answer's a better one overall, though.